# C# async doesn't await

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous, async-await, task

The app I'm working on is supposed to retrieve a json string with the http client after which it gets deserialised and used in the app.

Everything works, except for the await functionality. I'm doing something wrong and I can't seem to figure out what. How can I make sure that my DataService class waits untill I have my json and it has been deserialized?

The DataService class:

```
class DataService : IDataService
{
    private IEnumerable<Concert> _concerts;

    public DataService()
    {
        _concerts = new DataFromAPI()._concerts;

        Debug.WriteLine("____Deserialization should be done before continuing____");

        **other tasks that need the json**

    }
}
```

My http client class:

```
class DataFromAPI
{

    public IEnumerable<Concert> _concerts { get; set; }

    public DataFromAPI()
    {
        Retrieve();
    }

    public async Task Retrieve()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            var result = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://url-of-my-api"), HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
            string jsonstring = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            DownloadCompleted(jsonstring);
        }
        catch {}

    }

    void DownloadCompleted(string response)
    {
        try
        {
            _concerts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Concert>>(response.ToString());

        }
        catch {}
    }
}
```

**solution**

After a lot of trial and error I realised that for this particular thingy it didn't have to be async, so I just recreated is on the main thread, with success:

The DataService class:

```
class DataService : IDataService
{
    private IEnumerable<Concert> _concerts;

    public DataService()
    {
        _concerts = new DataFromAPI()._concerts;
    }
}
```

My http client class:

```
public static class DataFromAPI
{ 
    public void Retrieve()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            var result = client.GetAsync("http://url-of-my-api").Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseContent = result.Content;   
            }
            DownloadCompleted(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
        catch {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I realised that for this particular thingy it didn't have to be async, so I just recreated is on the main thread, with success:

The DataService class:

```
class DataService : IDataService
{
    private IEnumerable<Concert> _concerts;

    public DataService()
    {
        _concerts = new DataFromAPI()._concerts;
    }
}
```

My http client class:

```
public static class DataFromAPI
{ 
    public void Retrieve()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            var result = client.GetAsync("http://url-of-my-api").Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseContent = result.Content;   
            }
            DownloadCompleted(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
        catch {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You  are calling `Retrieve()` without  `await` in the `DataFromAPI` constructor, That's why your method isn't awaited.

You should better call this methods outside the constructor, with the await keyword like this :

```
await Retrieve();
```

You have to refactor your code a little. Here's an example :

```
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    private IEnumerable<Concert> _concerts;

    public async Task LoadData()
    { 
        _concerts = await DataFromAPI.Retrieve();
        **other tasks that need the json**
    }
}

public static class DataFromAPI
{ 
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<Concert>> Retrieve()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            var result = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://url-of-my-api"), HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
            string jsonstring = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Concert>>(response.ToString());
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<Concert>();
    }
}
```

Then, when you create your `DataService` instance, just after you have to call it's `LoadData()` method.

```
DataService ds = new DataService();
await ds.LoadData();
```

And of course, these two lines of code must also be called from an async method. (async / await all the way)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where to put Retrieve() if I can't put it inside the constructor, but I honestly don't have a clue about where to put it.

Comment: Just after the `DataFromAPI` constructor : `var temp = new DataFromAPI()` and then just after `await temp.Retrieve();`

Comment: You mean putting it outside of a method?

Comment: Yes, I mean putting the `await temp.Retrieve();` call outside from the `DataFromAPI` class.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. I can't put it outside of a method. I can't put it outside of the class. If I put it in the DataService class it gives an error on the await temp.retrieve().

Comment: Because it's the same problem for your DataService class : you will call an async method from within the constructor. I'll put an example in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but now it gives an error on the "response" in "return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Concert>>(response.ToString());" -> The name response doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: This one is another problem :) At least you solved the async one :)

Comment: + the idea was to contain the "getting the data"-part to the DataFromAPI class, so it would be easy to build another class later and use that one insted.

Comment: I'll go break my head a little more then :-)

Comment: If you want to go a little deeper on the async / await question, I can recommend you this excellent and brilliant blog : http://blog.stephencleary.com/

Comment: As a general rule, constructors should never do long operations, network operations, or any operations prone to inconsistent behavior.